# Odd behaviour in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, mstest

I have a batch file for execuntg a series of test runs using mstest.

```
mstest /testmetadata:matrix.vsmdi /testlist:"Build Server" /runconfig:TestRunConfig_Matrix.testrunconfig /resultsfile:BuildServer.trx > %outPath%
mstest /testmetadata:matrix.vsmdi /testlist:"Build Server API" /runconfig:TestRunConfig_Matrix.testrunconfig /resultsfile:BuildServer_API.trx >> %outPath%
mstest /testmetadata:matrix.vsmdi /testlist:"Build Server Scheduler" /runconfig:TestRunConfig_Matrix.testrunconfig /resultsfile:BuildServer_Scheduler.trx >> %outPath%
```

The first line correctly outputs to a new log file %outPath%. I expect the 2nd and 3rd lines to append to this log file.

However, bizarrely I am finding that the 1st line correctly creates a new log file, but the 2nd line overwrites it, yet the 3rd line correctly appends to the 2nd line's output. Consequently I never get to see the 1st line's output!

Am I losing my sanity, or is there a rational explanation for this?

Comment: What happens if you swap lines 2 and 3?

Comment: it takes a while to run - I'll get back in half an hour.

Comment: Interestingly, swapping the  2nd and 3rd lines fixes the problem! Any ideas why?

Comment: Hmm.. not my forte, unfortunately. If each mstest command is definitely running to completion prior to the next command beginning, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

In all probabiity, you are indeed losing your sanity. It's a fact of life in the IT biz - normally caused by having an IT Luddite for a boss.

As for your problem, I'd suggest that since `mstest` is an executable, your procedure will be running the three commands in parallel, not sequentially. Hence the data written to the file will likely depend on the sequence in which the processes terminate.

The theoretical solution would be to force the three processes to be invoked sequentially,

```
start /w "" mstest /testmetadata:matrix.vsmdi /testlist:"Build Server" /runconfig:TestRunConfig_Matrix.testrunconfig /resultsfile:BuildServer.trx > %outPath%
```

(ie prefix each line with `start /w ""`) this should start the following process only when the current has terminated.

The empty pair of rabbit's ears is important. This is the title of the window created - it can be any string of your choosing, but must exist and be first, else doom will strike. Well, not doom exactly, but batch will then choose the first quoted string in the line as the windows title, and likely ignore it as a parameter, leading to unexpected results.

---

Redirection and `start` don't play together nicely.

I'd try

```
CALL mstest /testmetadata:matrix.vsmdi /testlist:"Build Server" /runconfig:TestRunConfig_Matrix.testrunconfig /resultsfile:BuildServer.trx > %outPath%
```

Which should solve the problem.

Possibly if that doesn't work, try creating a simple batch file:

```
@echo off&setlocal
mstest /testmetadata:%~1 /testlist:"%~2" /runconfig:%~4 /resultsfile:%~5 > %~6
exit
```

and invoke it with `start`:

```
start /w "" simplebatch matrix.vsmdi "Build Server" TestRunConfig_Matrix.testrunconfig BuildServer.trx %outPath%
```

(and similar lines for the other two instances)

Comment: I'll give that a go. You could well be right, because the first test list is probably the longest running, although it doesn't explain why swapping the 2nd and 3rd lines fixes it - they are both shorter than the first.

Comment: Nearly works - but instead of the output being directed to the log file (ie %outPath%) as before, it is now directed to STDIO (ie the screen).